# How to add POI in Wikitude API for iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

I am working on one Agumented Reality application on iPhone. I have to use Wikitude API for my non - commercial application. I have gone through your Sample application of Wikitude but it is not woking on the Simulator. It is giving many errors. But on the Device it is working properly but giving two following warnings

1. ld: warning: directory '/Users/..../Desktop/WikitudeAPI-SCM-Test/../WikitudeAPI-SCM/build/Debug-iphoneos' following -L not found
2. ld: warning: directory '/Users/..../Desktop/WikitudeAPI-SCM-Test/../../../Desktop/WikitudeAPI' following -L not found

Please Suggest me some thing to resolve these warnings.

And one more question

Does apple allows the usage of this API?

Waiting for your reply.

Thanks,

Sha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the described warning may appear when building the Wikitude sample application for iPhone.
To remedy the warning you have to goto the target's build settings and set the "Library Search Paths" option to "$(SRCROOT)/WikitudeAPI/**"

Apple allows Apps using the Wikitude API with no problems.

Regards,
Nicolas

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nicolas
Now after setting the "Library Search Paths" option to "$(SRCROOT)/WikitudeAPI/**" the above mentioned warnings are not coming. 
Thanks a lot